# Tif image not creating thumbnail in Umbraco 10

Tags: umbraco

When I upload a .tif image to the Media library in Umbraco 10, it seems to upload OK but doesn't show a thumbnail.

"tiff" and "tif" are listed in appSettings.json

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs? The appsettings is, I believe, only a matter of being allowed to upload files of that type, not whether it's actually "supported". Although, Umbraco showing width and height does reveal it knowing it's an image type file. Which version of ImageSharp is in Umbraco 10? ImageSharp only got TIFF support last year (in version 2.0), I believe. https://sixlabors.com/posts/announcing-imagesharp-200/#what's-new-since-v1

Comment: @JannikAnker I can't see any error messages in the logs. I tried an upload and then looked immediately but nothing. The version of ImageSharp installed is 2.1.3